# "error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token validation failure. Invalid audience, Flutter MSGraph

Tags: flutter, azure, microsoft-graph-api

Im trying to call ms graph for basic user information in my application. After logging in to the application, i try to use the token i get from my application, but it aint the same token that i need to use for graph...

Code used for login

```
final Config configHardwareHouse = Config(
  tenant: "-",
  clientId: "-",
  scope: "User.Read",
  webUseRedirect: true,
  redirectUri:
      "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf",
  navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  loader: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
  postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://your_base_url/logout', //optional
);

final Config configA8 = Config(
  tenant: "-",
  clientId: "-",
  scope:
      "api://-/user_impersonation User.Read",
  webUseRedirect: false,

  redirectUri: "-",
  navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  loader: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
  postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://your_base_url/logout', //optional
);

final AadOAuth oauthHardwarehouse = AadOAuth(configHardwareHouse);
final AadOAuth oauthA8 = AadOAuth(configA8);
```

Code used for accessing graph.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:hardwarehousev2/presentation/auth/auth_config.dart';
import 'package:hardwarehousev2/presentation/models/user_response.dart';
import "package:http/http.dart" as http;

// import '../auth/auth_config.dart';
class User {
  late String displayName;
  late String givenName;
  late String surname;
  late String? jobTitle;
  late String mail;
  late String? officeLocation;

  static const _storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  static User? _user;

  User(UserResponse data) {
    displayName = data.displayName;
    givenName = data.givenName;
    surname = data.surname;
    jobTitle = data.jobTitle;
    mail = data.mail;
    officeLocation = data.officeLocation;
  }

  static Future<User?> getUser() async {
    String? accessTokenHardwarehouse =
        await _storage.read(key: 'currentUserToken');
    print(accessTokenHardwarehouse);
    if (accessTokenHardwarehouse != null) {
      Map<String, String> headers = {
        "Authorization": accessTokenHardwarehouse,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      };
      final http.Response response = await http.get(
          Uri.parse("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"),
          headers: headers);

      if (response.statusCode > 299) {
        print("Error getting user: ${response.statusCode}");
        print(
            "Response body: ${response.body}"); // Added to check server response.
        return null;
      }

      final data = UserResponse(jsonDecode(response.body));
      return _user = User(data);
    } else {
      return _user;
    }
  }

  static Future<User?> getCachedUser() async {
    if (_user != null) {
      return _user;
    } else {
      return getUser();
    }
  }

  static Future<void> updateCurrentUserToken(String newAccessToken) async {
    await _storage.write(key: 'currentUserToken', value: newAccessToken);
  }

  static Future<String?> getCurrentUserToken() async {
    return await _storage.read(key: 'currentUserToken');
  }

  static Future<void> updateCurrentUserRefreshToken(
      String newRefreshToken) async {
    await _storage.write(
        key: 'currentUserRefreshToken', value: newRefreshToken);
  }

  static Future<String?> getCurrentUserRefreshToken() async {
    return await _storage.read(key: 'currentUserRefreshToken');
  }
}
```

Token i aquire from the Config is shorter in length than the one used in ms graph, am i missing something or? it was working up untill recently after implementing other api's

(please tell me if there is information missing to find this issue)

error log:
Response body: {"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.","innerError":{"date":"2024-01-29T12:29:01","request-id":"-","client-request-id":"-"}}}

Ive tried all scope combinations as i thought that would be the issue at first...

Comment: Could you decode the token by pasting it in [jwt,ms](https://jwt.ms) and check what values `aud` and `scp` claims have?

Comment: To call MS Graph API, your token audience should be `https://graph.microsoft.com`

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, but ive tested that, im at my wits end but i though of something while making this question, give me a sec

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you want to use Microsoft Graph, your token can only hold one scope/aud. Thus, I tried making another Config for use in only msgraph, and that seemed to solve the problem.

```
final Config configMSGraph = Config(
  tenant: "-",
  clientId: "-",
  scope: "User.Read",
  webUseRedirect: true,
  redirectUri: "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf",
  navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  loader: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
  postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://your_base_url/logout', //optional
);
```